# Check for messages apache Qpid

Tags: shell, message-queue, messaging, amqp

Is it possible to check for messages from Qpid queue from unix/windows console?

Here is how I check via GUI :

http://i47.tinypic.com/pbu5d.gif

I can see all the info from Qpid JMX Management Console, is there a something close to this that I can use in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`qpid-tool`](http://qpid.apache.org/management-tools-overview.html) looks like it will do what you want. There's more documentation available from [redhat](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.1/html/Messaging_User_Guide/sect-Messaging_User_Guide-Command_Line_Tools-Using_qpid_tool.html).

Comment: how can I install this tool on Centos and/or ubutnu?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you say check means to read message. If so, there are two VERY useful tools in python-qpid that are drain and spout within examples/api directory. spout sends messages to broker and drain reads from broker. You can type --type to get usage.

In the other hand, qpid-queue-stats can show each queue status, like how many messages exists in each queue currently.

Answer (score 1):

To install qpid-tools on Centos :

```
yum install qpid-tools
```

on ununtu :

```
apt-get install qpid-tools
```